# Zooming with AVCaptureDevice and AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, gpuimage, avcapturedevice

I have a photo app when I want to support zooming up to 4x without pixelation. Currently I zoom by transforming the whole view:

```
previewImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(value, value);
```

This pixelates my image view, and is especially noticeable at my desired max zoom (4x). Is there a way to get a higher res preview for zooming? Currently I'm using *AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh*, but I want something up to 4x higher resolution. How do I get a high resolution preview?

Maybe I could use *AVCaptureSessionPresetInputPriority* could work? Any tips?

Or is there an easier, more performant way to do this within GPUImage?